# Half-precision PyTorch float tensors have same performance as single precision float tensors?

Tags: c++, optimization, pytorch, gpu, libtorch

Background: I've implemented the antiobject/"field AI" pattern ([https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~ralex/papers/PDF/OOPSLA06antiobjects.pdf](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Eralex/papers/PDF/OOPSLA06antiobjects.pdf)) for single diffusion using LibTorch/PyTorch.

This works fine, but in the process of running it on the GPU and optimizing it, I've run into a problem. I have a Titan V, which I believe excels at half-precision float math. However, when I make the tensors `torch::kHalf`, the performance is the same. (I've also tried `torch::kFloat16`). Any ideas?

The code that I timed is in `update()`:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include <simple2d.h>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <c10/cuda/CUDAStream.h>
#include <ATen/cuda/CUDAEvent.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>

#define DEBUG_NO_DRAW

torch::Device gpu(torch::kCUDA);
torch::Device cpu(torch::kCPU);
torch::Device device = gpu;

const int windowLength = 1000;
const int64_t length = 500;
const float diffusionRate = 0.25;
const int obstacleCount = 4000;
const int entityCount = 1000;

float cellLength = windowLength / length;
torch::Tensor scent = torch::zeros({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor up, down, left, right;
torch::Tensor topWallMask = torch::ones({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor bottomWallMask = torch::ones({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor leftWallMask = torch::ones({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor rightWallMask = torch::ones({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor obstaclesMask = torch::ones({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
torch::Tensor entities = torch::zeros({ length, length }, device).to(torch::kHalf);
c10::cuda::CUDAStream stream = c10::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream();

std::time_t *lastFpsUpdate = NULL;
std::time_t *currentTime = new std::time_t();
int frameAccumulator = 0;
std::vector<long> updateDurations;

void update() {
    torch::NoGradGuard no_grad;

    AT_CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    down = scent.roll(1, 0) * obstaclesMask * topWallMask;
    up = scent.roll(-1, 0) * obstaclesMask * bottomWallMask;
    right = scent.roll(1, 1) * obstaclesMask * leftWallMask;
    left = scent.roll(-1, 1) * obstaclesMask * rightWallMask;
    scent = scent + ((down - scent) + (up - scent) + (right - scent) + (left - scent)) * diffusionRate;
    scent = torch::max(scent, entities);

    AT_CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
    auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime - startTime);
    updateDurations.push_back(duration.count());
}

void render() {
    if (lastFpsUpdate == NULL) {
        lastFpsUpdate = new std::time_t();
        std::time(lastFpsUpdate);
    }
    
    torch::Tensor sqrtedScent = scent.sqrt().to(torch::kFloat).to(cpu); // just to make darker scents a little brighter for display
    auto obstaclesMaskCPU = obstaclesMask.to(torch::kFloat).to(cpu);

    auto sqrtedScentAccessor = sqrtedScent.accessor<float, 2>();
    auto obstaclesMaskAccessor = obstaclesMaskCPU.accessor<float, 2>();
    float r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;

#ifndef DEBUG_NO_DRAW
    S2D_DrawQuad(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        windowLength, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        windowLength, windowLength, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, windowLength, 0, 0, 0, 1);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (obstaclesMaskAccessor[i][j] == 0) {
                r = 1; g = 1; b = 1; a = 1;
            }
            else {
                r = 1; g = 0; b = 0; a = sqrtedScentAccessor[i][j];
            }

#ifndef DEBUG_NO_DRAW
            S2D_DrawQuad(cellLength * j, cellLength * i, r, g, b, a,
                cellLength * (j + 1), cellLength * i, r, g, b, a,
                cellLength * (j + 1), cellLength * (i + 1), r, g, b, a,
                cellLength * j, cellLength * (i + 1), r, g, b, a);
#endif
        }
    }

    frameAccumulator++;

    std::time(currentTime);
    if (std::difftime(*currentTime, *lastFpsUpdate) > 1.0) {
        std::cout << "FPS: " << frameAccumulator << std::endl;
        frameAccumulator = 0;
        *lastFpsUpdate = *currentTime;

        int updateCount = updateDurations.size();
        long totalUpdateTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < updateCount; i++) {
            totalUpdateTime += updateDurations[i];
        }
        long averageUpdateTime = totalUpdateTime / updateCount;
        std::cout << "AverageUpdateTime: " << averageUpdateTime << "us" << std::endl;
        updateDurations.clear();
    }
}

int main() {
    if (torch::cuda::is_available()) {
        std::cout << "CUDA is available!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Using " << (device == cpu ? "CPU" : "GPU") << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        topWallMask[0][i] = 0;
        bottomWallMask[length - 1][i] = 0;
        leftWallMask[i][0] = 0;
        rightWallMask[i][length - 1] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < obstacleCount; i++) {
        int x = rand() % length;
        int y = rand() % length;
        obstaclesMask[x][y] = 0;
    }

    //std::cout << obstaclesMask << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < entityCount; i++) {
        int x = rand() % length;
        int y = rand() % length;
        if (obstaclesMask[x][y].item() == 0)
            continue;
        entities[x][y] = 1;
    }

    S2D_Window* window = S2D_CreateWindow(
        "Collab Diffuse", windowLength, windowLength, update, render, 0
    );
    S2D_Show(window);

    return 0;
}
```

In both single precision and half precision versions of the code, `update()` takes about 2700 microseconds.

I'm using PyTorch/LibTorch 1.7.1.

Any other performance tips would be appreciated. (I'm aware drawing pixel by pixel is very slow, so I plan to switch from Simple2D to something else that can draw bitmaps from memory).

Comment: @talonmies may I ask why you removed the PyTorch and cuda tags? Even if someone is only familiar with PyTorch in Python, they may have some insight since the API is so similar.

Comment: it seems stackoverflow no longer allows at-mentions so I'll rollback and await your response.

Comment: You are running code on a GPU. You are not programming in CUDA. The C++ library you are using puts your code 2-4 levels of framework/library abstraction away from the first piece of code which is written in CUDA. So you question is about the implementation and performance of those 2-4 levels of abstraction. That is why I removed the tag, and will do so again